# VBA macro - is there a way to find only whole words?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, search, find

How can I alter this code to find only whole words? Currently it searches any instance of the word. Also, how to either suppress the message box or have it auto select "Yes". This is a macro I'm trying to get to work in Microsoft Word based on Find and Replace.

```
Sub ReplaceFromTableList()
Dim oChanges As Document, oDoc As Document
Dim oTable As Table
Dim oRng As Range
Dim rFindText As Range, rReplacement As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim sFname As String
Dim sAsk As String
    sFname = "C:\Users\tmoore\Desktop\Changes_Comps.docx"
    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set oChanges = Documents.Open(FileName:=sFname, Visible:=False)
    Set oTable = oChanges.Tables(1)
    For i = 1 To oTable.Rows.Count
    Set oRng = oDoc.Range
    Set rFindText = oTable.Cell(i, 1).Range
    rFindText.End = rFindText.End - 1
    Set rReplacement = oTable.Cell(i, 2).Range
    rReplacement.End = rReplacement.End - 1
    With oRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        Do While .Execute(findText:=rFindText, _
                          MatchWholeWord:=True, _
                          MatchWildcards:=False, _
                          Forward:=True, _
                          Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
            oRng.Select
            sAsk = MsgBox("Replace - " & vbCr & oRng & vbCr + vbCr & _
                          "with - " & vbCr & rReplacement, vbYesNo, _
                          "Replace from Table")

            If sAsk = vbYes Then
                oRng.FormattedText = rReplacement.FormattedText
            End If
            oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
  Next i
  oChanges.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: Hi Dave, basically I tried the above code and it worked but it finds every instance for example it finds "dog" when the only word I'm trying to replace is "dogma". That's just an example and not something I'm trying to find and replace. I was thinking the code could be tweaked to find whole words only?

Comment: You described what the code does. Not what you've tried to change

Answer (score 1):

As a quick answer, you can suppress the messagebox by removing (or commenting out) the line

```
sAsk = MsgBox("Replace - " & vbCr & oRng & vbCr + vbCr & _
                      "with - " & vbCr & rReplacement, vbYesNo, _
                      "Replace from Table")
```

and then change

```
If sAsk = vbYes Then
            oRng.FormattedText = rReplacement.FormattedText
        End If
```

into

```
oRng.FormattedText = rReplacement.FormattedText
```

But a better way to have a closer look at how you are using `.find`. There is a `.replacement.text` property under .find, and you can use `Replace:=wdReplaceAll` when executing. From memory, using the "replace all" option means that you don't have to have the `.find.execute` in a loop.

I haven't had a close look at the rest of your code (e.g. `While x=True` can just be `While x`) but I can't see anything obvious that addresses your initial question about not selecting the whole word (you already have `MatchWholeWord` set).

Comment: Thank you for the high quality answer, welcome to superser!